# Couchbase map-reduce query to fetch list of tags

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase

How can I count all unique languages from documents set like this?

```
{
  "type": "post",
  "lang": "en",
  "title": "one",
}

{
  "type": "post",
  "lang": "en",
  "title": "two",
}

{
  "type": "post",
  "lang": "en",
  "title": "three",
}

{
  "type": "post",
  "lang": "martian",
  "title": "four",
}
```

Map could look like this

```
function map(doc, meta) {
  if (meta.type !== "json") {
    return;
  }
  var type = doc["type"];
  if (!type || type !== "post") {
    return;
  }
  var lang = doc["lang"];
  if (!lang) {
    return;
  }
  emit(lang, null);
}
```

I use `group_level` 1 and group is set to `true`. Built-in function `_count` returns number of documents in each language (value 3 for `en` and 1 for `martian`). How can I reapply reduce to reduced values? Or this should be done on client?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually write your map logic like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json") {
    if(doc.type && doc.type == "post") {
      if(doc.lang) {
        emit(doc.lang); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think it looks clearer and easier to understand at a glance.  I would actually keep the count reduce rather than writing a new reduce function for this usage and as you said just do the filtering in the application layer.

Comment: I think its a matter of coding style, for me every "if" has subtle "else", so I like to use "if not" guards to make it clear :) Back to original question — seems Couchbase doesn't have "rereduce" and "views for views" option? I see they are working on N1QL lang to keep up with Mongo queries, but N1QL doesn't work on Couchbase Lite

Comment: You can implement what you want in the reduce section that handles rereduces too but as I said this would be the sort of thing I'd handle in the coding layer. Good luck!

Comment: Could you provide example of rereduce? Because from what I've seen this is impossible...

Comment: I meant "reduce what was already reduced" of course, not rereduce